# How to make a update informing page when store is updating products in Asp.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I update product like price or name on back-end, I want front-end users access only one page in a site: informing page with content: 'We're updating products, please comeback later'. And some client who is buying products with action: Add to cart or go to cart will be cancel and redirect to informing page

Comment: Any amount of downtime = lost sales.  Rethink what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi josh3736, I appreciate your comment, if any amount of downtime = lost sales, how do i overcome it? I want the customers will served with the newest product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment placed by josh3736, that you may wish to rethink it.

However one way you can look at implementing this is by overriding the BeginRequest method in the global.asax file

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(ShouldIShowMessage())
       {
           this.Response.Redirect("RedirectUrl");
       }
    }

    private bool ShouldIShowMessage()
    {
       // Decision logic here
    }
```

Comment: If the front-end user are viewing page, how do I refresh page for them? I just ask what do I think about it, sorry if it's not real